# Has anyone migrated Spring Security from 3.1.2 to 5.1.4

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

Team

Just trying to migrate Spring Security from 3.1.2.RELEASE to 5.1.4.RELEASE. We are using xml based configuration and checking if there is any reference around that helps me in this activity.

I have done the changes and resolved most of run time issues except the below one. I believe it is also not making any call to the user details service.

> SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: Eagerly created session:
>   a4931bcd-f260-4382-ad88-46237bed8fce  10:43:35,192 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3 - [2019-03-15
>   10:43:35,192] - DEBUG - HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:
>   HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT 
>   10:43:35,192 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3)
>   http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3 - [2019-03-15 10:43:35,192] - DEBUG -
>   HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: No SecurityContext was available
>   from the HttpSession:
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@32436149.
>   A new one will be created.

Below is the configuration I've in our code.

```
<bean id="securityContextRepository"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
```

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 3):

For a first step please refer to the [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html) for Update Spring Security 3 to 4.
Migrating to Spring Security 5 is then a rather small step and mainly about [password migration](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#migrating-to-spring-security-5).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. In fact, I followed the same documentation for this migration. Everything looks good but somehow SecurityContext is not getting stored in the session.

Comment: Below is the config details I've in our code.                                                                                               
 <bean id="securityContextFilter"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
  <constructor-arg ref="securityContextRepository" />
  <property name="forceEagerSessionCreation" value="true" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="securityContextRepository"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />

Comment: Could you please put this in your original question, that everybody has all necessary information needed to help you?

Comment: Added the details in my original question.

Comment: Please add also your `pom.xml` and the relevant Spring Security config files you have so far in use. Until this is done, it would be more or less guessing.

Comment: The issue related to session got resolved. Seems my war module did not pickup latest jars. Started building all the modules then it worked with the same configuration.